# React redux state update isn't reflecting to related components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have two react components namely Dashboard and singleFeature.In the dashboard I have an ionRangleSlider which takes value from redux state. And I'm rendering the singleFeature component inside the Dashboard. SingleFeature component creates a fetch network request and updates the redux state using the dispatch method.

And the ionRangeSlider which resides inside the Dashboard takes value from the redux state which gets updated by singleFeature component. But regardless of whatever I have tried it's not reflecting the ionRangeSlider. However I can see the redux state is getting updated but not reflecting in any of the component.

Codes:

Dashboard.js

```
<div id="slider"><IonRangeSlider ref={r => this.ionSlider = r} 
skin={this.state.skin} values={this.state.values} /></div>

<SingleFeature name={this.state.name} id={this.state.id} user={this.state.user} />

componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState) {
        if (this.props.dates !== prevProps.dates) {
            console.log(`In update`)
            this.ionSlider.update({ values: this.props.dates })
        }
    }
```

Which then goes to singleFeature and runs a function and updated the redux state.

singleFeature.js

```
fetch(`http://api/dates`)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(res => {
            for(let i in res){
                let dates = res[i]["dates"];
            }
            this.props.updateState(dates)
        })


    componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState) {
        
        if (this.props.dates !== prevProps.dates) {
            console.log(`In update`)
            console.log(this.props.dates)
        }
    }
```

And both components are connected by { connect } by `react-redux` which runs these methods.

```
//fetch from redux store
const FetchFromStore = (state) => {
    return {
        dates: state.dates
    }
}

//update redux store functions
const UpdateStore = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        updateState: (dates) => dispatch(
            {
                type: 'UPDATE_DATES',
                payload: dates
            })
    }
}
```

And the reducer file,

```
const stateActions = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_DATES':
            state.dates = [...state.dates,...action.payload];
            console.log(state.dates) //which is updating
            return state;
    }
    return state;
}
```

None of the `componentdidUpdate` method working after state update.

Comment: If you can see that the Redux state is changing, the culprit is likely your component. Have you tried logging inside the `componentDidUpdate` of your component? My guess is that your  `this.props.dates !== prevProps.dates` condition is wrong. You can compare length if possible, or you can try something like `JSON.stringify(this.props.dates) !== JSON.stringify(prevProps.dates)`

Comment: Yes. I have tried by logging inside the componentdidUpdate method. But it's not giving any output.

Comment: In your update you put the `console.log` inside your condition. If the condition is wrong, you won't see an output. Please try putting it outside this condition.

Comment: Yes. I have added `console.log(this.props.dates)` inside the `componentdidUpdate` but not consoling any ouput.

Comment: It is also possible your component is not connected to your Redux store. Have you looked at this? https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Comment: It's actually connected.
`export default connect(FetchFromStore, UpdateStore)(singleFeature)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments. It appears to be I'm updating the state in a wrong way.

```
//redux payload actions
const stateActions = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_DATES':
            // state.dates = [...state.dates,...action.payload];
            let dates_arr = [...state.dates];
            state.dates = [...dates_arr,...action.payload]
            return {...state}
    }
    return state;
}
```

Which is working fine and updating all the components.